# Count occurences of all items of a list in a tuple

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple `(1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)` and a list `[1,2,3]` and now want to count how often all items of the list occur in the tuple (so it should return `7`).

I could loop the list, count each item in the tuple and then sum up the results, but I bet there is a better possibility in python.

Thats not a duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) because I explicitly said that I am not just asking for `list.count(item_of_list)` (that would need to be done in a loop) but for a better method.

Comment: its definitely not the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item, because here is not asked for the simple count() method but for a good method how to count all items of a list within a tuple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being NumPy tagged, here's a NumPy solution -

```
In [846]: import numpy as np

In [847]: t = (1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)

In [848]: a = [1,2,3]

In [849]: np.in1d(t,a).sum()
Out[849]: 7

# Alternatively with np.count_nonzero for summing booleans
In [850]: np.count_nonzero(np.in1d(t,a))
Out[850]: 7
```

Another NumPy one with `np.bincount` for the specific case of positive numbered elements in the inputs, basically using the numbers as bins, then doing bin based summing, indexing into those with the list elements to get the counts and a final summation for the final output -

```
In [856]: np.bincount(t)[a].sum()
Out[856]: 7
```

Other approaches -

```
from collections import Counter
# @Brad Solomon's soln
def collections_counter(tgt, tup):
    counts = Counter(tup)
    return sum(counts[t] for t in tgt)

# @timgeb's soln
def set_sum(l, t):
    l = set(l)
    return sum(1 for x in t if x in l)

# @Amit Tripathi's soln
def dict_sum(l, t):
    dct = {}
    for i in t:
        if not dct.get(i):
            dct[i] = 0
        dct[i] += 1
    return sum(dct.get(i, 0) for i in l)
```

**Runtime tests**

Case #1 : Timings on a tuple with `10,000` elements and with a list of `100` random elements off it -

```
In [905]: a = np.random.choice(1000, 100, replace=False).tolist()

In [906]: t = tuple(np.random.randint(1,1000,(10000)))

In [907]: %timeit dict_sum(a, t)
     ...: %timeit set_sum(a, t)
     ...: %timeit collections_counter(a, t)
     ...: %timeit np.in1d(t,a).sum()
     ...: %timeit np.bincount(t)[a].sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 437 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 503 µs per loop
```

`set_sum` from @timgeb's soln looks quite efficient for such inputs.

Case #2 : Timings on a tuple with `100,000` elements that has `10,000` unique elements and with a list of `1000` unique random elements off it -

```
In [916]: t = tuple(np.random.randint(0,10000,(100000)))

In [917]: a = np.random.choice(10000, 1000, replace=False).tolist()

In [918]: %timeit dict_sum(a, t)
     ...: %timeit set_sum(a, t)
     ...: %timeit collections_counter(a, t)
     ...: %timeit np.in1d(t,a).sum()
     ...: %timeit np.bincount(t)[a].sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 21.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.33 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.05 ms per loop
```

Comment: @timgeb I bet that's where its getting the performance efficiency as well.

Answer (score 3):

Define a `set` of your target values (for the O(1) membership-test) and combine the `sum` builtin with a generator expression.

```
>>> t = (1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l = set(l)
>>> 
>>> sum(1 for x in t if x in l)
7
```

Answer (score 2):

With `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
tup = (1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)
tgt = [1, 2, 3]
counts = Counter(tup)
sum(counts[t] for t in tgt)
# 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [25]: t= (1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)

In [26]: l = [1,2,3]

In [27]: sum(t.count(i) for i in l)
Out[27]: 7
```

On [juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s comment, I have implemented a solution that takes more memory but its more efficient. It trades space for complexity. If not using numpy like library this will be efficient and its equivalent to using itertools.groupby. Its complexity will be O(n+m) in the worst case.

```
In [43]: t = (1,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,4,3)

In [44]: l = [1,2,3]

In [45]: dct = {}

In [46]: for i in t:
    ...:     if not dct.get(i):
    ...:         dct[i] = 0
    ...:     dct[i] += 1
    ...:

In [47]: sum(dct.get(i, 0) for i in l)
Out[47]: 7
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution if `l` is small, but it essentially iterates over `t` for each item in `l`. Again, if `l` is small, this won't be a big issue, but will become problematic as `l` becomes bigger.

Comment: thats more or less the solution I explicitly didn't want to to have

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated the answer with a new approach.