# Find with python numpy the amount of combinations in tuple

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple `(1,2,5,3,2,1,3,4,1)` and want to find the amount of combinations of `1` and `2`. So in this example it should return `2` because there are 3 times a `1` but only 2 times a `2`.

The task that I want to solve is:

> Give the amount of possible combinations by `1` and `2`. Each number can only be used once for a combination.

I already solved the issue with this code:

```
    count1 = tuple.count(number1)
    count2 = tuple.count(number2)
    if count1 < count2:
        return count1
    else:
        return count2
    return count1
```

But because I want to learn more magic things with `numpy`, I would like to know if there is a better solution to use it here.

Comment: In what way is this the "amount of combinations"?  Looks more like the minimum count to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "the amount of combinations of 1 and 2"? It's not clear whether your existing code is correct.

Comment: [Do not repost a question just because the other one was closed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518293/count-occurences-of-all-items-of-a-list-in-a-tuple)

Comment: its another task than in the other question, here the combinations should be found, not the all occurences

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clearly, please stop downvoting just because you don't understand the task. Better ask so I can improve the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if/else` can be expressed more compactly with `min`:

```
In [707]: tup = (1,2,5,3,2,1,3,4,1)
In [708]: max(tup.count(1), tup.count(2))
Out[708]: 3
In [709]: min(tup.count(1),tup.count(2))
Out[709]: 2
```

`numpy` won't improve on this.  There is a `bincount`, that counts all values in a range.

```
In [710]: arr = np.array(tup)
In [711]: arr
Out[711]: array([1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1])
In [712]: np.bincount(arr)
Out[712]: array([0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

We could select a could select a couple of values and as before get their min:

```
In [716]: np.bincount(arr)[[1,2]]
Out[716]: array([3, 2], dtype=int32)
In [717]: min(np.bincount(arr)[[1,2]])
Out[717]: 2
```

Keep in mind that `np.array(tup)` takes time; so sticking with list operations is often faster.

Another array approach is to use a broadcasted `==` test

```
In [532]: arr == [[1],[2]]
Out[532]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [533]: _.sum(axis=1)
Out[533]: array([3, 2])
```

using sum on the booleans to count them.

There's also `Counter` class that can count all values in one call:

```
In [534]: from collections import Counter
In [535]: Counter(tup)
Out[535]: Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
In [536]: min(_[1],_[2])
Out[536]: 2
```

Comment: where the `_` variable in some lines comes from?

Comment: thanks for the nice solution with `min()` and that you showed that `numpy` wouldn't make it easier here.